# Inter-component communication not working in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data between two components. But I am getting an error Here is the child component,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: '[app-bar-chart]',
    templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() chartData: {
        title: string,
        content: {
            label: string,
            value: number,
            fill?: string
        }[]
    }[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        alert(this.title);
    }    


}
```

Here is the parent component,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    template: `<div>
    <div class="graph-image" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" app-bar-chart [chartData]="barChartData"></div>
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    barChartData = [
        {
            "title": "May2017",
            "content": [
                {
                    "label": "payable",
                    "value": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Jun2017",
            "content": [
                {
                    "label": "payable",
                    "value": 120
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

I am using @Input decorator for inter-component communication. When I am running the app it showing an error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'chartData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

Please note that these two components are in separate modules and I am using lazy loading. Why this happens? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that app-bar-chart should be in its own tag like this

```
 <div class="graph-image" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
<app-bar-chart [chartData]="barChartData"></app-bar-chart>
</div>`
```

Also, remove the `[title]` in your app-bar-chart because you only declare the `chartData` as your input.

If you are lazy-loading your modules, then just use a shared module and declare the BarChartComponent there. Using two components that belong to different modules with lazy-loading will not work, because they don't know each other.

Hope this helps

Comment: What if I want to use an attribute selector?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry if I may not get it clearly can you elaborate it more?

Comment: if you want to use [title[ in your app-bar-chart declare another @Input() title

Comment: I have edited the question and removed [title]. And I tried your answer. Still the issue exists.

Comment: have you moved the app-bar-chart to its own tag? if no you will still have the problem. Please read again my answer I separated the app-bar-chart from the div

Comment: Hey, there seems to have a problem. I am lazy loading my modules. When I tried your solution it showed 'app-bar-chart is not a known component of angular'. When I moved the deceleration of BarChartComponent into child module, it works perfectly even without separating app-bar-chart from div.

Comment: The 2 components should be declared in the same module. You can do lazy-loading but the other component should be in a router-outlet and is entirely a different question from the original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did mention in the question that the two components are in different modules. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. Another tip would be put that component in a sharedModule or just duplicate it in your modules. That's the con of using lazy-loading but nothing serious that could affect your app

Comment: I used a shared module and added the child component in exports, then imported the shared module where ever I wanted. It's working perfectly as I wanted. Thank you very much for your directions. It helped me a lot. I have edited the question. Why don't you post this as your answer so that I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the property instead of specifying all the values. When pass the value from Parent to Child all the values getting replaced by the chartData

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() chartData:any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        alert(this.title);
    }    


}
```

Also you can't use Component as Attribute Directive

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be used without the brackets:

```
selector: 'app-bar-chart'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use the selector as an attribute selector. And even if I tried that, the issue won't solved.

Answer (score -2):

you have to define chartData as @Output in parent component.

Comment: Please refer the official documentation link of Angular: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
They are not using @Output in the example. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Output decorator is used to interact from Parent Component to Child Component and Input is used to interact from Child to Parent Component

Comment: It should be @input not output